# Installing MongoDB Driver for php gone wrong (windows)

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, xampp

I have followed the instructions on the following link:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.windows.php

But when i try one of the following comands:

```
composer require jenssegers/mongodb

composer require jenssegers/mongodb:dev-develop

composer require jenssegers/mongodb --ignore-platform-reqs
```

They all return the same error:

```
 Using version ^3.7 for jenssegers/mongodb
 ./composer.json has been updated
 Loading composer repositories with package information
 Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
 Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Conclusion: don't install jenssegers/mongodb v3.7.0
- Installation request for jenssegers/mongodb ^3.7 -> satisfiable by jenssegers/mongodb[3.7.x-dev, v3.7.0].
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- jenssegers/mongodb 3.7.x-dev requires illuminate/events ^7.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/events[7.x-dev, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v7.11.0, v7.12.0, v7.13.0, v7.14.0, v7.14.1, v7.15.0, v7.16.0, v7.16.1, v7.17.0, v7.17.1, v7.17.2, v7.18.0, v7.19.0, v7.19.1, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.20.0, v7.21.0, v7.22.0, v7.22.1, v7.22.2, v7.22.3, v7.22.4, v7.23.0, v7.23.1, v7.23.2, v7.24.0, v7.25.0, v7.26.0, v7.26.1, v7.27.0, v7.28.0, v7.28.1, v7.28.2, v7.28.3, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].
- don't install illuminate/events 7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.0.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.0.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.0.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.0.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.1.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.10.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.10.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.10.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.10.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.11.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.12.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.13.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.14.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.14.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.15.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.16.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.16.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.17.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.17.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.17.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.18.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.19.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.19.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.2.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.2.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.20.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.21.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.22.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.22.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.22.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.22.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.22.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.23.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.23.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.23.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.24.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.25.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.26.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.26.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.27.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.28.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.28.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.28.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.28.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.5.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.7.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.8.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.9.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.9.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- don't install illuminate/events v7.9.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
- Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.6.38, required as 5.6.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.6.38].
```

What i have tried:

- Restart the xampp
- Many different versions of monogodb dlls. Both thread safe and non thread safe. My phpinfo page shows that Thread Safety is enabled so i guess i should choose the thread safe version but i have tried both just in case but both wont work. I have even tried the x86 version just incase.
- i have tried "composer require jenssegers/mongodb:dev-develop" and "composer require jenssegers/mongodb --ignore-platform-reqs" but the same error occurs

what could be the problem?

php version          7.4.9

laravel version      8.6.0

the mongodb dll iam trying to use is the latest one (php_mongodb-1.8.0-7.4-ts-vc15-x64) As i said i have tried older ones aswell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read that error message? It does not contain any reference to mongodb, but tells you that you currently have installed `laravel/framework` in v5.6.38. This is not compatible with the latest version of `jenssegers/mongodb`.

Try installing it using `composer require jenssegers/mongodb:"^3.5"`

Additionally, you should also plan to update Laravel. v5.6.38 is more than two years old, and you will face more incompatibilities with libraries if you wait longer.